# Xamarin Forms Device.OpenUri not working for files

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have tried to open an Image that was downloaded and saved in local storage but when I do the following nothing happens on iOS. On Android, it looks like an app handles it but crashes on startup. Heres the code:

```
if(File.Exists(filename))
      Device.OpenUri(new Uri(filename));
```

Why does this not work? The path looks good.
WebUri's are working, only files do not open.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this is also helpful: 
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        var filename = Path.Combine(folder, "TempRecordImage.jpg");

Comment: Make sure you used the right uri, can you please show the exception info?

Comment: There is no Exception. Just nothing happens.

Comment: This is the Uri: {file:///data/user/0/PackageName/files/.local/share/TempRecordImage.jpg}

Comment: If the uri is right, it should work, but the code to get file just looks like for Android platform. Do you mind to use `DependencyService` to implement such feature on each platform?

Comment: Thats what I just did now. And I think I found the problem. Photos App on Android tells me "Media not found". But the Xamarin System.IO.File.Exists() Method tells true. So do I have to save it in a more public folder?